# Memory leak when freeing and reassigning pointers in an array

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to implement a genetic algorithm to solve sudoku puzzles. I have an array of pointers to specimen solutions (int*'s), so I choose one to replace with a newly bred specimen - that is, free the memory pointed at, then make it point to the new specimen. My code at the moment has a memory leak, but I don't know why. Here's my main:

```
int main(){

    //somewhere... is a memory leak.

    srand(time(NULL));

    int puzzle[] = {6,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   
                    9,0,0,0,7,1,2,0,6,   
                    1,8,2,5,0,0,0,0,9,   
                    7,0,0,6,4,5,8,1,0,   
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   
                    0,1,8,3,2,9,0,0,5,   
                    2,0,0,0,0,7,9,4,8,   
                    3,0,1,8,5,0,0,0,7,   
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,3};  

    int** population = generate_population();

    //ensure each specimen contains the puzzle-defined cells.
    for (int i=0; i<POP_SIZE; ++i){
        for (int j=0; j<81; ++j){
            if (puzzle[j] && population[i][j] != puzzle[j]){
            population[i][j] = puzzle[j];
            }
        }
    }

    //Create array of fitnesses for original population.
    int fitness[81];
    for (int i=0; i<POP_SIZE; ++i){
         fitness[i] = calculate_fitness(population[i]);
    }

    int average_fitness = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<POP_SIZE; ++i){
        printf("Specimen %i: Fitness: %i\n", i, fitness[i]);
        average_fitness += fitness[i];
    }
    printf("Average fitness: %f\n\n", (double)average_fitness/POP_SIZE);


    int* mother = NULL;
    int* father = NULL;
    int* child = NULL;

    int mother_index = 0;
    int father_index = 0;
    int exiled_index = 0;

    //Do some evolving
    for (int i=0; i<GENERATIONS; ++i){

        //choose parents.
        mother_index = choose_parent(fitness);
        father_index = choose_parent(fitness);

        if (mother_index == -1 || father_index == -1){
            //problems
            printf("CHOOSE_PARENT RETURNED -1!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        mother = population[mother_index];
        father = population[father_index];

        //Breed mother and father, and mutate ensuring child conforms to puzzle definition.
        child = mutate(crossover(mother, father), puzzle);

        //Choose specimen to be removed, free the memory it takes up, and reallocate
        //the pointer with the new specimen.
        exiled_index = choose_exiled(fitness);
        free(population[exiled_index]);
        population[exiled_index] = child;

        //Update fitness array with new specimen's fitness.
        fitness[exiled_index] = calculate_fitness(population[exiled_index]);
    }


    //After evolution
    average_fitness = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<POP_SIZE; ++i){
        printf("Specimen %i: Fitness: %i\n", i, fitness[i]);
        average_fitness += fitness[i];
    }
    printf("Average fitness: %f\n\n", (double)average_fitness/POP_SIZE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Within the evolution for-loop, crossover creates a new array of 81 ints (which is mutated then stored in child), and later we free whatever is stored in population[exiled_index], and reassign that pointer to the new child. So surely, this loop should maintain the same amount of memory in use? Well, it doesn't! I've got no idea where memory is going.

Here are the crossover and mutate functions:

```
int* crossover(int* const mother, int* const father){
    int* child = malloc(sizeof(int)*81);
    for (int i=0; i<81; ++i){
        if (rand()%2){
            child[i] = mother[i];
        }
        else {
            child[i] = father[i];
        }
    }
    return child;
}

int* mutate(int* const child, int* puzzle){
    for (int i=0; i<81; ++i){
        if (child[i] == puzzle[i]){
            continue;
        }
        else if ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX < 0.125){
            child[i] = 1+rand()%9;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

I can provide more code if it's wanted, but I don't think the rest will be needed to explain the leak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging? The easiest way is to simply print relevant information after each line of code, or just after the ones you think is the root of your problem. This will help you trace your problem.

Comment: @savram Yes, I know the basics of gdb. I don't know (and my sources do not tell of) how to examine the memory allocated at a point in the program. How could I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have a memory leak? Have you used `valgrind` to determine it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am sure. I tried this with 5 million generations - the program was taking nearly 9GB of RAM by the time it finished. I've not heard of valgrind.. I shall look into that.

Comment: BTW:the program could be much simpler if you omitted dynamic allocation and just perturbed some static arrays.(the number of elements is constant)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?